# is it Codeigniter Issue or something else?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing php code using Codeigniter. My script is working fine in my localhost but when i am moving to server some part of script stop working. Its kind of a simple registration from.

When i am running script in firefox it showing me:

The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading...
.....
.......

[view error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVaMl.png)

**This error show when i press submit button and post the form**

### Controller Class

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->model('register_model');
    } 
    public function index()
    {
        //echo 'user_full_name:' .$this->input->post('user_full_name', TRUE);
        $data['page_title'] = 'Couple Dating Website - Registration';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                //echo "<br>Validation Not Success";
                $this->load->view('register_view',$data);
            }
            else //If validation success
            {
                $this->load->view('register_view',$data);
            }
    }
    public function success()
    {
        $data['page_title'] = 'Couple Dating Website - Registration Success';
        $this->load->view('register_success_view',$data);
    }
    public function add() { 

            $data['page_title'] = 'Couple Dating Website - Registration';

            //Form Validation 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[members.email]',array('is_unique' => '%s is already registered with us.'));
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass_confirmation', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Confirm Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name_p1', 'Partner 1 Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name_p2', 'Partner 2 Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob_mm', 'Month of Partner 1 Birthday', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob_dd', 'Day of Partner 1 Birthday', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob_yy', 'Year of Partner 1 Birthday', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob_mm2', 'Month of Partner 2 Birthday', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob_dd2', 'Day of Partner 2 Birthday', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob_yy2', 'Year of Partner 2 Birthday', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('relationship_status', 'Relationship Status', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('we_are', 'We Are', 'required');

            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert-danger">', '</div>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                //echo "<br>Validation Not Success";
                $this->load->view('register_view',$data);
            }
            else //If validation success
            {
                //Get Current Date and Time
                //$this->load->helper('functions');
                //echo get_current_datetime();
                //$date_added = get_current_datetime();
                $date_added = '2017-01-01 05:50:00';
                //P1 DOB
                $dob_p1 = $this->input->post('dob_yy', TRUE) . '-' . $this->input->post('dob_mm', TRUE) . '-' . $this->input->post('dob_dd', TRUE);  
                //P2 DOB
                $dob_p2 = $this->input->post('dob_yy2', TRUE) . '-' . $this->input->post('dob_mm2', TRUE) . '-' . $this->input->post('dob_dd2', TRUE);  

                //echo "<br>Validation Success";
                    $input_data = array( 
                        'email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE),
                        'password' => md5($this->input->post('pass_confirmation', TRUE)),
                        'first_name_p1' => $this->input->post('first_name_p1', TRUE),
                        'first_name_p2' => $this->input->post('first_name_p2', TRUE),
                        'dob_p1' => $dob_p1,
                        'dob_p2' => $dob_p2,
                        'relationship_status' => $this->input->post('relationship_status', TRUE),
                        'we_are' => $this->input->post('we_are', TRUE),
                        'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE),
                        'status' => '1',
                        'date_added' => $date_added,
                        'date_updated' => $date_added
                    ); 
                    $res = $this->register_model->insert($input_data); 

                 if($res)
                 {
                    //Send Welcome email
                    $message = 'Dear '.$this->input->post('first_name_p1', TRUE).',';
                    $message .= '<br><br>Welcome to BeeOurFriends.com ! ';
                    $message .= "<br><br>Thanks";
                    $message .= "<br>BeeOurFriends.com";
                    $this->send_mail($this->input->post('email', TRUE),$message);

                    redirect('register/success');
                 }
                // 
            }

        } 

        public function send_mail($to_email,$message) { 

         $from_email = "donotreply@beeourfriends.com"; 
         $to_email = $this->input->post('email'); 

         //Load email library 
         $this->load->library('email'); 

         $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
         $this->email->from($from_email, 'BeeOurFriends.com'); 
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Forget Password'); 
         $this->email->message($message); 

         //Send mail 
         if($this->email->send()) 
         $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Email sent successfully."); 
         else 
         $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Error in sending Email."); 
         //$this->load->view('email_form'); 
    } 

}
?>
```

### Model

```
<?php
//session_start();
Class Register_model extends CI_Model
{
  function __construct() { 
     parent::__construct(); 
  } 


    public function insert($data) { 
        //echo "<br> Insert";

        if ($this->db->insert("members", $data)) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 


}
?>
```

### View

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>

<div class="profile_banner">
    <div class="container"> 
       <h3>Register</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='profiles'>
  <div class="container">
      <?php echo form_open(base_url() .'register', array('id' => 'registration-form-main','method' => 'post')); ?>

       <div class="register">
                 <div id="alert_success" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert" style="display:<?php if(validation_errors() != "") echo 'block'; else echo 'none'?>">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> </button>
        <?php echo validation_errors();  ?> </div>
                 <div class="register-top-grid">
                        <h3>ACCOUT INFORMATION</h3>
                         <div>
                            <span>Email<label>*</label></span>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-validation="email" value="<?php echo set_value('user_email') . set_value('email'); ?>"> 
                         </div>
                         <div>
                             <span>Password<label>*</label></span>
                             <input type="password" name="pass_confirmation" id="pass_confirmation" data-validation="strength" data-validation-strength="2" data-validation-error-msg="Pasword has to be an alphanumeric and a special char"> 
                             <?php //echo form_error('pass_confirmation'); ?>
                         </div>
                         <div>
                             <span>Confirm Password<label>*</label></span>
                             <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" data-validation="confirmation"> 
                             <?php //echo form_error('pass'); ?>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                     <div class="register-bottom-grid">
                            <h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
                             <div>
                                <span>Partner 1 Name<label>*</label></span>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name_p1" id="first_name_p1" data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="2-25" value="<?php echo set_value('user_full_name').set_value('first_name_p1'); ?>">
                             </div>
                             <div>
                                <span>Partner 2 Name<label>*</label></span>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name_p2" id="first_name_p2" data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="2-25" value="<?php echo set_value('user_full_name2').set_value('first_name_p2'); ?>">
                             </div>
                             <div>
                                <span>Partner 1 Birthday<label>*</label></span>
                                 <select id="dob_mm" name="dob_mm" class="select-box" style="width:100px;" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg=" ">
                                    <option value="">MM</option>
                                    <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?>" <?php if(set_value('dob_mm')== sprintf("%02d", $i)) echo 'selected';?> ><?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?></option>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                                 </select>
                                 <select id="dob_dd" name="dob_dd" class="select-box" style="width:100px;" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg=" " >
                                    <option value="">DD</option>
                                    <?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?>" <?php if(set_value('dob_dd')== sprintf("%02d", $i)) echo 'selected';?> ><?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?></option>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                                 </select>
                                 <select id="dob_yy" name="dob_yy" class="select-box" style="width:100px;" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg=" " >
                                    <option value="">YYYY</option>
                                    <?php for($i=1910;$i<=2020;$i++) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if(set_value('dob_yy')== sprintf("%02d", $i)) echo 'selected';?> ><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                                 </select>
                             </div>
                             <div style="float:left">
                                <span>Partner 2 Birthday<label>*</label></span>
                                <select id="dob_mm2" name="dob_mm2" class="select-box" style="width:100px;" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg=" ">
                                    <option value="">MM</option>
                                    <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?>" <?php if(set_value('dob_mm2')== sprintf("%02d", $i)) echo 'selected';?> ><?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?></option>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                                 </select>
                                 <select id="dob_dd2" name="dob_dd2" class="select-box" style="width:100px;" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg=" " >
                                    <option value="">DD</option>
                                    <?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?>" <?php if(set_value('dob_dd2')== sprintf("%02d", $i)) echo 'selected';?> ><?php echo sprintf("%02d", $i); ?></option>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                                 </select>
                                 <select id="dob_yy2" name="dob_yy2" class="select-box" style="width:100px;" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg=" " >
                                    <option value="">YYYY</option>
                                    <?php for($i=1910;$i<=2020;$i++) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if(set_value('dob_yy2')== sprintf("%02d", $i)) echo 'selected';?> ><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                                 </select>
                             </div>
                             <div>
                                <span>Relationship Status<label>*</label></span>
                                <select id="relationship_status" name="relationship_status" class="select-box" data-validation="required">
                                    <option value="">-----</option>
                                    <option value="In Relationship" <?php if(set_value('relationship_status')== "In Relationship") echo 'selected';?> >In Relationship</option>
                                    <option value="Engaged" <?php if(set_value('relationship_status')== "Engaged") echo 'selected';?> >Engaged</option>
                                    <option value="Married" <?php if(set_value('relationship_status')== "Married") echo 'selected';?> >Married</option>
                                </select>
                             </div>
                             <div>
                                <span>We are a<label>*</label></span>
                                <select id="we_are" name="we_are" class="select-box" data-validation="required">
                                    <option value="">-----</option>
                                    <option value="Man and Woman" <?php if(set_value('we_are')== "Man and Woman") echo 'selected';?> >Man and Woman</option>
                                    <option value="Man and Man" <?php if(set_value('we_are')== "Man and Man") echo 'selected';?> >Man and Man</option>
                                    <option value="Woman and Woman" <?php if(set_value('we_are')== "Woman and Woman") echo 'selected';?> >Woman and Woman</option>
                                </select>
                             </div>
                             <div>
                                <span>Location<label>*</label></span>
                                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" data-validation="required" placeholder="City, State or Zipcode" value="">
                             </div>
                             <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                     </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                  <a class="news-letter" href="#">
                         <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" data-validation="required"><i> </i>I Agree terms of use </label>
                       </a>
                <div class="register-but">
                       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn1 btn-1 btn1-1b">
                       <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn1">
                       <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
           </div>

           <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

Comment: which part is it?

Comment: when i post the form then that error comes

Comment: can you include the error in your post

Comment: Please check the address shown at your browser's location bar after submitting the form. It is correct?

Comment: i checked it is coming correct address in browser location bar.

Comment: Problem solved...i just change password field name 'pass' to 'pass2' and its started working....wow

Comment: @GiteshSao Checking your error logs will help you to find the root cause for this issue.